# How can we make the echarts responsive

Tags: echarts

Charts responsive - When we take a view of chart  in higher resolution screens, it will change the width responsively according to viewport width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resize chart on menu width change and window resize

```
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('ChartDivID'));

$(window).on('resize', resize);

// Resize function
function resize() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Resize chart
    myChart.resize();
  }, 200);
}
```

Comment: You have a redundant  `});` in your code and you are using `myChart` instance to resize the component while you initialized it with `myChart2`.